# TRESTRequest: How to add query string parameters to a PUT request

Tags: delphi, rest

I'm using the Delphi [REST.Client](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/REST.Client) components, and want to send a request like this:

```
PUT http://hostname/api/items?arg=value
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
req := TRESTRequest.Create(nil);
req.Client := FRESTClient;
req.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPUT;
req.Resource := 'api/items';
req.AddParameter('arg', 'value');
req.AddBody(someJSONObject);
req.Execute;
```

However, Fiddler indicates that the parameters are **not** being included in the request, and the server rejects the request as badly formatted.

```
PUT http://hostname/api/items HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 123
Connection: keep-alive
Host: hostname
Accept: application/json, text/plain; q=0.9, text/html;q=0.8,
Accept-Charset: UTF-8, *;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: Embarcadero RESTClient/1.0
```

In the Delphi debugger, I can see that the [parameter kind](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/REST.Types.TRESTRequestParameterKind) being used is `pkGETorPOST` (the default). I don't see any values for Kind that seem like they would solve this problem.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? The documentation on many of these classes is [not](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/REST.Client.TCustomRESTRequest.AddParameter) [very](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/REST.Client.TRESTRequest.Params) [helpful](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/REST.Client.TRESTRequest.AutoCreateParams).

Comment: Have you tried to simply append the parameters to the Resource property like `api/items?arg=value` ?

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to get the parameter into the query part using `TRESTRequest` with `rmPOST`/`rmPUT`.

On `GET` the `pkGETorPOST` parameters are put into the query part, but on `POST`/`PUT` these parameters are placed into the request body. This is as designed.

There is a - well, ugly - workaround

```
req := TRESTRequest.Create(nil);
req.Client := FRESTClient;
req.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPUT;
req.Resource := 'api/items?arg={arg}';
req.AddParameter( 
  { AName } 'arg', 
  { AValue } 'value', 
  { AKind } TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkURLSEGMENT );
req.AddBody( someJSONObject );
req.Execute;
```

The [*normal* REST PUT request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Applied_to_web_services) (expected by me) would be something like this

```
PUT http://hostname/api/items/item17
```

and this is handled by the Delphi REST client

```
req.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPUT;
req.Resource := 'api/items/{itemid}';
req.AddParameter( 
  { AName } 'itemid', 
  { AValue } 'item17', 
  { AKind } TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkURLSEGMENT );
req.AddBody( someJSONObject );
```

On my REST servers I use the header for additional data

```
FRESTClient.AddParameter( 
  { AName } 'context', 
  { AValue } 'foocontext', 
  { AKind } TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER );

req.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
req.Resource := 'api/items';
req.AddBody( someJSONObject );
```

If there is a possibility to change the REST server behaviour change it, otherwise use the workaround.

Answer (score -1):

Add a parameter by using this syntax:

```
FRESTRequest.Params.AddItem('Accept',
                            'application/json, */*; q=0.01',
                            TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER);
```

where `TRESTRequestParameterKind` can take the value

```
pkGETorPOST
```

which is used for the `POST` and `PUT` commands.

Comment: Is the `, */*; q=0.01` actually required? IIRC this allows the server to send a different content type than json, but this is not useful for the Delphi REST library

Comment: Is pkHTTPHEADER right? HTTP headers are no query string parameters.